# Django template loop

Tags: python, django, templates

debug is answering me that there is any `if` without `endif` tag.

```
{% for j in content.numpaginas %} 
    {% if j == content.actpag %}
        <li class="active blue-grey"><a href="{{ j }}"></a></li>
    {% else %}
        <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!"></a></li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor }
```

Comment: You are missing `%` in your last line: `{% endfor %}`

Answer (score 0):

replace `=` with `==`

```
{% if j == content.actpag %}
```

Comment: doesn't work yet: Invalid block tag: 'endif', expected 'empty' o 'endfor'

Comment: Well you must have another unclosed `if` statement somewhere. Look at the template you extend and the templates you include.

Answer (score 0):

Django also have `{% ifequal foo bar %}` tag.

See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/).